# Blazor server app Scaffolding failed. Could not load information for project

Tags: asp.net, blazor-server-side

[image]

Working on a N'Tier App, trying to Scaffold Identity but it failed and I got this error

Comment: This question is asked in the worst way possible, explain your error, what you've already tried and please do not post error messages (or code) as images. See [mcve] and [help]

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` package to version `6.0.10`. Then it should work, but please work on how you ask questions.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design/6.0.10